# The Double Limit Problem [Part 2]

Tags: limits

Excuse me.

I have a double limit problem, that is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{y} = \,?
\end{equation}
I also don't know, whether, generally
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{y\to b}f(x, y) = \lim_{y\to b}\lim_{x\to a}f(x, y)
\end{equation}
where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f\,:\,\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $y \ne 0$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{y}=0.$ Hence

$$\begin{equation}
\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{y} = \,0
\end{equation}.$$

If $x \ne 0$, then $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{x}{y}$ does not exist. Hence

$$\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{x}{y} 
\end{equation}$$

does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question, **no** it is not always the case that
$$\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{y\to b}f(x, y) = \lim_{y\to b}\lim_{x\to a}f(x, y) $$

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer.

Now, if the question is changed to be
\begin{equation}
\left(\lim_{x\to 0}x\right)\left(\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{y}\right) = \,?
\end{equation}
What is the answer of this question?